# PHP strip the content to fix number of lines

Tags: php, css, stripping

What is the best way in PHP to strip the content to fix number of lines?

When we strip the content by character length then sometimes its 5 lines and sometimes its 6 lines. This is due to the different width of individual character and size of word.

I have tried many things but didn't got any perfect solution for this.

What you guys feel?

With CSS we can set the height of the div and then add overflow hidden but when we want to add read more button with text then that trick also don't work.

Comment: What is your current code?

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 4):

This is more like a javascript or css question rather than php. If you want your content to fit into a fixed height check this jquery plugin: [dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/)

Obviously there are also CSS ways to achieve this. Like CSS3 [text-overflow](http://caniuse.com/text-overflow) which is partially supported (though with prefixes it seems pretty supportable).

Answer (score 1):

Use the PHP `wordwrap` function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php

In that, you can specify a width, and the lines are then returned using that width.

Comment: Or just use CSS: `div{width:960px;word-wrap:break-word;}`

Answer (score 0):

What you want is show all the content within a fixed area.
I think adding a scroll bar to your fixed height DIV will do the trick.

You need to add

> style="overflow-y:scroll;" to the div tag. (This will force a
>   scrollbar on the vertical).

If you only want a scrollbar when needed, just do

> overflow-y:auto;

Do whatever you need with the Text sizes, it will work.You won't make your text sizes 1000px ? Do you ? :)

Cheers.